# Grub rescue problem after deleting windows partition

Tags: grub2, partitioning

I accidently deleted the windows partition and now i am facing grub rescue problem.
I used this commands

```
Grub rescue> set root=(hd0)(msdos4)
Grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0)(msdos4)
Grub rescue> insmod normal
```

And the diaplay was

```
No such partition

ls (hd0) (msdos4) displayed filesystem is ext2
```

What should i do???

Answer (score 0):

The somehow easiest way would be to use Boot Repair Live CD /pen-drive  which you can find:
and follow these steps described here
[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
If you need more detailed help let me know.